# How map Observable object to Flowable<?> ?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

```
 private Observable< SimpleResource > resource;
 return resource.map(new Function<SimpleResource, Flowable<Data>>() {
  @Override
  public Flowable< Data > apply(SimpleResource resource) throws Exception {
    return resource.data().toFlowable();
  }
});


  Single<Data> data();
```

I need to have Flowable but my result is Observable>

Comment: will your `Observable<SimpleResource>` emit more than once? and will `resource.data()` return a `Single<Data>`? We need to know the answers to those questions before we can suggest a flexible solution

Comment: @Jon 
resource.data only once
and Observable<SimpleResource> is injected in my method ,for making Dependency Injection async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that `data()` returns a `Single`, you need to transform all of the single streams into one large stream. To transform streams into streams, we generally use the `flatmap` operator:

```
resource.flatMapSingle(
            new Function<SimpleResource, Single<Data>>() {
                @Override
                public Single<Data> apply(SimpleResource resource) throws Exception {
                    return resource.data();
                }
            }
    ).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
```

Comment: thanks Jon
I couldn't always understand when to use Observable, when Flowable,or there are some functions of RX which are working with Observables but not with Flowables, but you can work with Observables then convert it to Flowables, I don't understand how it works converting at the end to Flowable, and it could not effect ?

Comment: To put it simply: `Observable` is when you have a stream that will emit many items... but at a reasonable pace. `Flowable` is when you have a stream that can emit items faster than you can process them... so that stream will become "clogged" and you need a `BackpressureStrategy` to deal with that.

Comment: thanks for explaining, but how can I know it's going to emit items faster or not, I guess in most cases it's Observable case if it is Retrofit requests and Flowable if I'm listening to DB changes , is it?

Comment: Both could be either `Observable` or `Flowable`. It really depends on your use case. The [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable) has a good description on observable vs flowable and when to use them.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is applying `.toFlowable` at not the right spot.

```
Observable.fromCallable { 1 }.map {
    it * 2
}.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
```

If you have different data type returned by `data` (sorry for Kotlin, but the concept is the same)

```
data class A(
        val data: Single<Int>
) {
    constructor() : this(data = Single.fromCallable { 1 })
}


val result: Flowable<Int> = Flowable
        .fromCallable {
            A()
        }
        .flatMap {
            it.data.toFlowable()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but in my. cas data() returns Single which I need to convert to Flowable,
when I'm doing the way you mentioned, I'm getting Flowable<Single<Data>> but I need to have Flowable<Data>

Comment: `resource.map(SimpleResource::data).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)`. You need to expose your single first before converting it to flowable.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by posting this sample, Please could you explain a bit different way @Georgy Savatkov

Comment: @Jon 
thanks for reply ,but how can I expose first to Single ?